# Swift: macro for __attribute__((section))

Tags: swift, swift2, metaprogramming, mach-o

This is kind of a weird and un-Swift-thonic question, so bear with me.
I want to do in Swift something like the same thing I'm currently doing in Objective-C/C++, so I'll start by describing that.

I have some existing C++ code that defines a macro that, when used in an expression *anywhere in the code*, will insert an entry into a table in the binary at compile time. In other words, the user writes something like this:

```
#include "magic.h"

void foo(bool b) {
    if (b) {
        printf("%d\n", MAGIC(xyzzy));
    }
}
```

and thanks to the definition

```
#define MAGIC(Name) \
  []{ static int __attribute__((used, section("DATA,magical"))) Name; return Name; }()
```

what actually happens at compile time is that a *static variable* named `xyzzy` (modulo name-mangling) is created and allocated into the special `magical` section of my Mach-O binary, so that running `nm -m foo.o` to dump the symbols shows something a lot like this:

```
0000000000000098 (__TEXT,__eh_frame) non-external EH_frame0
0000000000000050 (__TEXT,__cstring) non-external L_.str
0000000000000000 (__TEXT,__text) external __Z3foob
00000000000000b0 (__TEXT,__eh_frame) external __Z3foob.eh
0000000000000040 (__TEXT,__text) non-external __ZZ3foobENK3$_0clEv
00000000000000d8 (__TEXT,__eh_frame) non-external __ZZ3foobENK3$_0clEv.eh
0000000000000054 (__DATA,magical) non-external [no dead strip] __ZZZ3foobENK3$_0clEvE5xyzzy
                 (undefined) external _printf
```

Through the magic of `getsectbynamefromheader()`, I can then load the symbol table for the `magical` section, scan through it, and find out (by demangling every symbol I find) that at some point in the user's code, he calls `MAGIC(xyzzy)`. Eureka!

---

I can replicate the whole second half of that workflow just fine in Swift — starting with the `getsectbynamefromheader()` part. However, the first part has me stumped.

- Swift has no preprocessor, so spelling the magic as elegantly as `MAGIC(someidentifier)` is impossible. I don't want it to be too ugly, though.
- As far as I know, Swift has no way to insert symbols into a given section — no equivalent of `__attribute__((section))`. This is okay, though, since nothing in my plan *requires* a dedicated section; that part just makes the second half easier.
- As far as I know, the only way to get a symbol into the symbol table in Swift is via a local struct definition. Something like this:

  ```
  func foo(b: Bool) -> Void {
      struct Local { static var xyzzy = 0; };
      println(Local.xyzzy);
  }
  ```

That works, but it's a bit of extra typing, and can't be done inline in an expression (not that that'll matter if we can't make a `MAGIC` macro in Swift anyway), and I'm worried that the Swift compiler might optimize it away.

---

So, there are three questions here, all about how to make Swift do things that Swift doesn't want to do: Macros, attributes, and creating symbols that are resistant to compiler optimization.

I'm aware of `@asmname` but I don't think it helps me since I can already deal with demangling on my own.

I'm aware that Swift has "generics", but they seem to be closer to Java generics than to C++ templates; I don't think they can be used as a substitute for macros in this particular case.

I'm aware that the code for the Swift compiler [is now open-source](https://github.com/apple/swift); I've skimmed bits of it in vain; but I can't read through *all* of it looking for tricks that might not even be there.

Comment: I feel Swift is just too high level for such kind of work. C exists for a reason.

Comment: @BryanChen: The solution is allowed to involve calling a C/ObjC function. But it must be usable from Swift, because that's the language in which the application/business-logic code is written, and the application/business logic is the one that needs to use the `MAGIC`. That is: "Write parts of the implementation of `MAGIC` in Objective-C" is an acceptable answer in this context (but needs implementation details fleshed out, obviously). "Continue writing all of your application logic in Objective-C so that you can continue using the old `MAGIC`" is *not* an acceptable answer in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer to your question about preprocessor (and macros).

> Swift has no preprocessor, so spelling the magic as elegantly as MAGIC(someidentifier) is impossible. I don't want it to be too ugly, though.

Swift project has a preprocessor (but, AFAIK, it is not distributed with Swift's binary).

From `swift-users` mailing list:

[What are .swift.gyb files?](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20151207/000227.html)

> It’s a preprocessor the Swift
>   team wrote so that when they needed to build, say, ten nearly-identical
>   variants of Int, they wouldn’t have to literally copy and paste the same
>   code ten times. If you open one of those files, you’ll see that they’re
>   mainly Swift code, but with some lines of code intermixed that are written in Python.

It is not as beautiful as C macros, but, IMHO, is more powerful.
You can see the available commands with `./swift/utils/gyb --help` command after cloning the Swift's git repo.

```
$ swift/utils/gyb --help
```

usage, etc (TL;DR)...

```
Example template:

      - Hello -
    %{
         x = 42
         def succ(a):
             return a+1
    }%

    I can assure you that ${x} < ${succ(x)}

    % if int(y) > 7:
    %    for i in range(3):
    y is greater than seven!
    %    end
    % else:
    y is less than or equal to seven
    % end

      - The End. -

When run with "gyb -Dy=9", the output is

      - Hello -

    I can assure you that 42 < 43

    y is greater than seven!
    y is greater than seven!
    y is greater than seven!

      - The End. -
```

My example of GYB usage is available on [GitHub.Gist](https://gist.github.com/b1narykid/e6687ed8726538b156f1).

For more complex examples look for `*.swift.gyb` files in [@apple/swift/stdlib/public/core](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/stdlib/public/core).

Answer (score 1):

[Recently](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/2d5f33e2e3cfdc8254f1ef1fa7716577a64cb2c8) two underscored attributes `@_used` and `@_section` has been added which are equivalent of `__attribute__(used)` and `__attribute__(section)` respectively. In my knowledge this is available only development snapshot of swift and is guarded by experimental feature flag `SymbolLinkageMarkers`.